# "расставлены" - одна или две "н"?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово *расставлены* пишется с двумя "с" и одной "н"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Расставлены: **рас** - приставка, **став** - корень, **л+ен** - суффикс. В суффиксах кратких причастий на **-ен-** всегда пишется одно Н.

Comment: Рас/став/и/ть - рас/ставл/ю,  разве Л относится к  суффиксу? Также: рас/ставл/енн/ый, рас/ставл/ен, вроде бы корень СТАВ/СТАВЛ?

Comment: Это по какой системе? Детям, может и проще видеть здесь корневое чередование. Только сколько таких чередований надо иметь?! *Ставленный, (вы)правленый, давленный, условленный, огрубленный, утомленный, закрепленный*... Чуть не для каждого корня  получите, оканчивающегося на М, Б, В, П (наверное не только)... . На самом деле Л тут - чисто фонетическое образование, своего рода протеза, только возникающая на стыке корня и суффикса, семантической нагрузки не имеет, а потому его куда удобнее отнести к суффиксу. Что ему в корне-то делать?

Comment: Ну да, Л появляется после губно-губных Б/П, М и губно-зубных В/Ф перед Е/Ё, Ю: любить - люблю, влюбленный, но: любит.  Мне кажется,  что Л удобно отнести к корню, так как чередование происходит и в  формах слова, а там суффикса нет. А что по этому поводу говорит официальная школьная наука, которая обычно занимается разборами?

Comment: Ну я вам уже ответил, что тогда придется признать чередование во всех таких корнях. А это Л появляется как рефлекс древнего суффиксального йота. Какой смысл пихать его в корень?

Answer (score 0):

Слово **расставлены** - краткое причастие, которое пишется всегда с одним Н. Здесь две буквы **сс** пишутся на стыке приставки и корня: ра**сс**тавлены.

Comment: Слово "расставить" - глагол.

Comment: Артём Луговой, я не думаю, что раз за разом исправляя на свой вкус ляпы Сержа, Вы оказываете услугу ему и ресурсу. Неблагодарное это дело - помогать тем, кто, не видя бревен в своем глазу, пытается найти соломинку в чужом. Да и вообще, при правке надо придерживаться авторского понимания.

Comment: Про бревно - это точно про вас. Вы следите лучше за своими ляпами. А их - уйма.

Comment: Серж, а чем Вы недовольны-то? Назвать глагол причастием - и ждать, что кто-то исправит... Бегемот при всех его недостатках вполне доброжелательно относится к указанию на его помарки.

Comment: Дело не в доброжелательности, а в том, что надо следить за своими ляпами.А спутал я не потому, что не отличаю глагол от причастия ( как бы вам этого хотелось) а по не внимательности.

Comment: Просто некоторые самомнением страдают....